# copy memory starting from an offset position

Tags: c++, offset, memcpy

how do i copy memory starting from a given offset. 
For example

```
int main()
{
   int a1[100], a2[100], i;
   errno_t err;

   // Populate a2 with squares of integers
   for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
      a2[i] = i*i;
   }

   // Tell memcpy_s to copy 10 ints (40 bytes), giving
   // the size of the a1 array (also 40 bytes).
   err = memcpy_s(a1, sizeof(a1), a2, 10 * sizeof (int) );    
   if (err)
   {
      printf("Error executing memcpy_s.\n");
   }
   else
   {
     for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       printf("%d ", a1[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

How do I copy memory from a2 to a1 starting at index 50 of a1.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add 50 to `a1`. No need to mess with sizeof for the addition; the compiler knows how to do it.

Comment: can you show me a code snippet. if char * data is the destination variable.

Comment: `err = memcpy_s(a1 + 50, 50 * sizeof(*a1), a2, 10 * sizeof (int) );` I hadn't noticed that the original code was using `memcpy_s`; for that, you also have to adjust the size of the target buffer.

Answer (score 6):

Pass the address to the index you want to copy to as the destination of `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(&a1[50], &a2[50], 10 * sizeof a[0]);
```

Comment: Or equivalently, `a1 + 50, a2 + 50`.

Comment: @delnan, yes. However, I personally prefer the way I wrote.